# Check if a check box is checked or not (js/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to check if a certain check box is selected using JavaScript/jQuery.

Here is the code I tried:

```
var a;
    if ($("#add_desc").checked == 1){
        a = "true";
    }else{
        a= "false";
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
var a;
    if ($("#add_desc").checked){
        a= "true";
    }else{
        a= "false";
    }
```

It always returns false once I alert the variable `a`.

Any idea why it won't work for me? Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Add `[0]` before `.checked` and use your second attempt

Comment: By way of explanation: `$('#add_desc')` returns a jQuery object that contains the element, rather than the element itself, so doesn't have a `checked` property. Adding the `[0]` returns the first element contained in the jQuery object (your actual checkbox), which **does** have a checked property.

Comment: You can also access those properties with jQuery 1.6's `.prop()`. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @CameronSpear You can, though to be honest this entire example is trivial enough that there's no need to use jQuery at all.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I've noticed you need to index jquery's id selector too. Why does it not say this in the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)? They do it like the OP is doing it..

Comment: @Shredder What are you referring to, the use of `[n]`?

Comment: @KevinB yes, the `[0]` you mentioned. that's not in the manual. how come? In the link to my last comment, the example they use is `$("#myDiv").css("border","3px solid red");` (no `[n]`)

Comment: @Shredder I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Calling the `jQuery()` function with an ID selector is the same as calling it with any other selector, it's not treated as some special case. It just happens to return a jQuery object that only ever contains one element.

Comment: @Shredder Ah, ok. It's in the documentation somewhere, though not in the page you linked because it doesn't belong there. Most (if not all) of the examples in the documentation call jQuery functions on jQuery objects, they don't work with the actual elements themselves.

Comment: @Shredder And, for the sake of completeness, it's documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/get/) in the documentation for the `.get()` function, which is designed to return either all of the elements in an array, or a specific element, depending on whether or not you pass it an argument.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ooh okay, I see now. Man, they don't specify that at all. In fact, the first sentence in my link is the id selector uses `document.getElementById()` >_< so you wouldn't think to use `[n]`. guess its not very specific

Comment: @Shredder Programmers aren't exactly known for their documentation ability, though the jQuery API is one of the better examples I've seen. The problem, really, is that people tend to drop in and out of documentation to find the specific parts they need, so they don't necessarily know things like this that are covered elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the value of the `checked` property on a checkbox input, use the `.prop()` method, or get the value directly from the DOM element. `[0]` returns the first selected DOM element.

```
var a;
if ($("#add_desc")[0].checked){
    a= "true";
}else{
    a= "false";
}
```

or

```
var a;
if ($("#add_desc").prop("checked")){
    a= "true";
}else{
    a= "false";
}
```

**Edit**
For versions of jQuery older than 1.6, `.prop` didn't exist, use `.attr` as a direct replacement.

Answer (score 6):

The "jQuery way" would be to use `.is(":checked")`:

```
var a;
if ($("#add_desc").is(":checked")){ // box is checked
    a = "true";
} else{ // box is not checked
    a= "false";
}
```

I use this a lot in my web apps and it works perfectly.

From the [jQuery `.is` documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

> Unlike other filtering methods, .is() does not create a new jQuery
>   object. Instead, it allows you to test the contents of a jQuery object
>   without modification. This is often useful inside callbacks, such as
>   event handlers.

Answer (score 6):

Simple,

```
var a = $('#element:checkbox').is(':checked');
```

Comment: That would make the variable a boolean while in his example he's assigning string values...

Comment: Yes. But how hard would it be to do a `toString()` if required?

Answer (score 4):

The [ternary](http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm) operator in javascript combined with jQuery [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) is the shortest solution.

```
var a = ($("#add_desc").is(":checked")) ? "true" : "false";
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
if ($('#add_desc').is(':checked')) {
  a = "true";
} else {
  b = "false";
}
```

you may also not want to use strings, i.e. use `true` and `false` instead of `"true"` and `"false"`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$get("#add_desc").checked == true
```

Also

```
$("#add_desc").prop("checked", true);
$("#add_desc").prop("checked", false);
```

Comment: Note that `.prop()` did not exist prior to jQuery 1.6. Use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for any earlier versions of jQuery.